# Audio onended not functioning

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

The audio plays when the user interacts with the window however when the audio ends it doesnt log 'audio ended'

```js
let audio = new Audio();

window.onclick = () => {
  if (audio.paused) pickMusic().play();
};

audio.onended = () => {
  console.log("audio ended");
};

function pickMusic() {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)) {
    case 0:
      return (audio = new Audio("/music/gorp.mp3"));
      break;
    case 1:
      return (audio = new Audio("/music/gorp.mp3"));
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere!</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new Audio()`, it will override the previous audio which is already attached with `onended` event.

In this case, whenever you call `new Audio()`, you also need to initialize `onended` event once again

```js
let audio = new Audio()

window.onclick = () => {
  if (audio.paused) pickMusic().play();
};

function pickMusic() {
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)) {
    case 0:
      audio = new Audio("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg")
      audio.onended = () => {
        console.log("audio ended");
      };
      return audio;
    case 1:
      audio = new Audio("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-brrring.m4a")
      audio.onended = () => {
        console.log("audio ended");
      };
      return audio;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere!</p>
```